# how to use TIdCookieManager save webbrowser cookie in different location

Tags: delphi, cookies

i want to load multi yahoo mail,
Example i have multi tab in delphi,
first tab load yahoo.com  ,
second tab also load yahoo.com,
But, when delphi Twebbrowser loaded same url, they will load the same cookie,
so second tab also load the same first tab email address.
how do i do first tab save the cookie in `c:\tab1` and second tab's cookie save in `c:\tab2'` ? so i can having a hundred tabs with yahoo.com's mail

i have been searched in google, i know that  `IdCookieManager;` able to control cookie,
 but i can't find any solution?

Comment: Indy's cookie manager is for managing cookies for use with the *Indy* components. Your Web browsers are not using Indy, so Indy's cookie manager will be useless here. The solution to your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

TWebBrowser is just a thin wrapper around Internet Explorer's ActiveX control.  As such, it uses Internet Explorer's cookies, cache, settings, etc.  You have no control to specify different folders for each TWebBrowser instance.

Comment: not necessary must use Twebbroswer, Any solution for my purpose ?

Comment: @C.Y Remy answered the question that you asked. If you asked the wrong question, then you ought to accept this answer, and then ask the question that will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, my answer is based on the presume, that you want to run a `TWebBrowser` in sandbox.*

The `TWebBrowser` is actually a wrapper of the [ActiveX control of MSIE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). MSIE has its own implementation of net communication, so that any 3rd party framework (such as Indy) cannot intercept/handle the net communication of a browser instance.

SFAIK, the `TWebBrowser` will read the most settings of MSIE from Registry. (not 100% but near to, [Feature Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are not included). The location for Cookies is also defined in Registry. If you are able to create a browser instance without loading settings from default location, you can save Cookies individually.

A doable approach would be to customize the ActiveX control itself. A good start point IMO is to create a descent of `TWebBrowser` class and inherit the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface. The next important thing is to override the `GetOptionKeyPath` method. Here is the [official document of the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041.aspx#GetOptionKeyPath) and here is a [code example](https://github.com/ghquant/Delphi-EmbeddedWB/blob/c8c3a2956c609a0b6f35f424bb269401dca6ece2/Source/EwbCore.pas) for your reference.

The browser customization is not an easy work. I hope the information can be helpful to you.

Comment: I don't think you can isolate a `TWebBrowser` instance.

Comment: In a single application -> not proved yet. But in a multiple process architecture, it works. I managed to isolate FeatureControls, proxy setting and MimeFilter of different browser instances by using this architecture already.